# Malloc() não funciona em código em C

Tags: c, array, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Ao tentar compilar o código eu recebo as seguintes mensagens de erro:

[image: Mensagem de erro no terminal]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OK 0

void preencherVetor(int* vetor[], int tamanho)
{

  int indice;

  for (indice = 0; indice < tamanho; indice++)
  {
    printf("Entre com o valor[%d]\n", indice+1);
    scanf("%d", vetor[indice]);
  }
}

void copiarVetor(int* novoVetor[], int* antigoVetor[], int tamanho)
{
  int indice;

  for (indice = 0; indice < tamanho; indice++)
  {
    (*novoVetor[indice]) = (*antigoVetor[indice]);
  }
}

int* somaVetores(int* vetorSoma[]/*, int tamanhoI, int tamanhoII*/)
{
  vetorSoma = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * 20);

  int indice = 0;
  int tamanho;
  int tamanhoI;
  int tamanhoII;
  int tamanhoExcedente; //Se os vetores possuírem tamanhos diferentes, o tamanhoExcedente será o tamanho do maior vetor
  int* maiorVetor[20];

  maiorVetor = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * 20);

  printf("\nDigite o tamanho do primeiro vetor\n(O valor do tamanho deve pertencer ao intervalo [1,20])\n");
  scanf("%d", &tamanhoI);

  printf("Digite o tamanho do segundo vetor\n(O valor do tamanho deve pertencer ao intervalo [1,20]\n");
  scanf("%d", &tamanhoII);

  int* vetorI[tamanhoI];
  vetorI = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * tamanhoI);

  int* vetorII[tamanhoII];
  vetorII = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * tamanhoII);

  printf("\nPreencha o primeiro vetor\n");

  preencherVetor(vetorI, tamanhoI);

  printf("\nPreencha o segundo vetor\n");

  preencherVetor(vetorII, tamanhoII);

  while ((tamanhoI >= 1) && (tamanhoI <= 20) && (tamanhoII >= 1) && (tamanhoII <= 20))
  {
    if (tamanhoI < tamanhoII)
    {
      tamanho = tamanhoI;
      tamanhoExcedente = tamanhoII;
      copiarVetor(maiorVetor, vetorII, tamanhoII);
    }

    else if ((tamanhoI) > (tamanhoII))
    {
      tamanho = tamanhoII;
      tamanhoExcedente = tamanhoI;
      copiarVetor(maiorVetor, vetorI, tamanhoI);
    }

    else
    {
      tamanho = tamanhoI; //Como neste caso os dois vetores possuem tamanhos iguais, *tamanho deve ser igual ao tamanho de qualquer um dos vetores
      tamanhoExcedente = tamanhoI;
      copiarVetor(maiorVetor, vetorI, tamanhoI);
    }

    for (indice = 0; indice < tamanho; indice++)
    {
      (*vetorSoma[indice]) = (int) ((*vetorI[indice]) + (*vetorII[indice]));
    }

    indice = tamanho;

    for (indice = tamanho; indice < tamanhoExcedente; indice++)
    {
      (*vetorSoma[indice]) = (*maiorVetor[indice]);
    }

    printf("\nVetor Soma = {");

    printf("%d", (*vetorSoma[0]));

    indice = 1;

    for (indice = 1; indice < tamanhoExcedente; indice++)
    {
      printf(", %d", (*vetorSoma[indice]));
    }

    printf("}\n");

    return *vetorSoma;
  }

  printf("ERRO\n O tamanho de um vetor excede o limite permitido!!!\n");

  return 0;
}



int main()
{
  int opcao;
  int* vetSoma;

  vetSoma = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * 20); //vetor soma

  do
  {
    printf("\nCALCULADORA DE VETORES E MATRIZES\n\n");
    printf("1 - Soma de dois vetores\n");
    printf("2 - Produto interno de dois vetores\n");
    printf("3 - Intercalação de dois vetores de 8 posições em um vetor de 16\n");
    printf("4 - Ordenação de um vetor de inteiros em ordem crescente\n");
    printf("5 - Transposta de uma matriz");
    printf("6 - Multiplicação de duas matrizes\n");
    printf("0 - Sair\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch (opcao)
    {
      case 1:
        somaVetores(&vetSoma/*, tamanho1, tamanho2*/);
        break;

      case 0:
        break;

      default:
        printf("Operação não disponível\n");
        break;
    }
  } while(opcao != 0);

    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Você poderia me dizer o que acontece quando você tira as conversões antes de malloc? É importante entender que em C, é ideal que você não faça conversão de tipos ao usar malloc. A própria linguagem faz a conversão implicitamente para você.

Comment: Você colocou #include <stdlib.h>?

Comment: Não mude a pergunta, se tem outro problema, faça outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro só gera um *warning* porque é só uma possibilidade de problemas, escreva assim e deve funcionar:

```
int* vetSoma = malloc(sizeof (int) * 20);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocCorrect.c).

Os demais não é possível usar `malloc()` já que eles são *arrays*, estão alocados no *stack*. Ao contrário da crença popular [*arrays* não são ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Ocorre o mesmo problema que eu havia informado na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204835/101). Você está querendo colocar uma carta no lugar onde se espera uma casa.

Ou transforme esses *arrays* em ponteiros, onde dá, ou não use `malloc()`, o que inviabilizará o uso do *heap*, aí tem que ver se é o que precisa. Se for usar só a *stack* terá que fazer cópias que talvez não sejam necessárias.

Após postar o código vi que o primeiro está como *array* também e portanto dá o mesmo erro, não pode fazer isto.

[O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)